# How to use ICustomTypeProvider over WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamic

I need to use an object extended from ICustomTypeProvider in my project for dynamic property support and it works fine but now i need to send this object over WCF service. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I suggest you start thinking about how to represent the dynamic data on the wire, in XML. After a while thinking about that, you may decide to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

WCF provides it's own mechanism for transporting custom data. That interface is called [IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx). Any data added to the [ExtensionDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject.aspx) can be accessed server side (this data does not need to be declared on the DataContract).